# Subwoofer Efficiency Ratings have Inverse Effects in Small Enclosures?

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics

I found this article on the internet which claims that higher sensitivity subwoofers have lower output in smaller boxes. http://stereointegrity.com/wp-content/uploads/Efficiency.pdf

Is this true or was this experimental error or bad manufacturer sensitivity measurements? If higher sensitivity woofers really do perform worse than lower sensitivity woofers, why?

Comment: The graphs in the PDF don't make any sense at all. The first graph claims a speaker that is "84dB efficient" (whatever that means!) produces more than 84dB of "output" (whatever that means!). Loudspeaker enclosure design *does* involve science, but you wouldn't guess that fact from a nonsense  "paper" like this one IMO.

Comment: @alephzero I thought it was funny how it claimed to be a "paper"

Answer (score 0):

all subwoofers have impaired efficiency in small enclosures. The degree of impairment has to do with the free-air resonance of the driver relative to the size of the enclosure, and whether or not the enclosure is ported.

Note however that for low-to-moderate playback loudness levels, small rooms, and modern amplifiers, any impairment of speaker response can be easily dealt with simply by turning up the amp's bass output level.